# Can a civilian helicopter regularly fly low & close to houses?

Tags: safety

There is a helicopter which regularly (1 to 5Xs a month) at night or day flies very low & fast, has flown over a vehicle, playing a chasing game down neighbor's driveway and down the road. Who can I report this to as it also has spooked pets and wildlife?

Comment: Which country and city is this? Any possible advice would need that information I think.

Comment: What do you mean by "playing a chasing game down a neighbor's driveway and down the road"? Are you talking about a remote-controlled helicopter, or a full-sized one?

Comment: You have no location information in your post or user profile. Obviously the answer depends on country.

Comment: For USA: [Under what conditions would a helicopter be allowed to fly at low altitude over populated areas?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26828/14897)

Answer (score 4):

The question as it stands now is asking one thing in the headline, and the other in the body. I'll answer the latter.

In any case of public disturbance your first point of contact is the police. If the disturbance is acute, you may call emergency number (depending on your location  911, 112 or something else).

You may also find out what is the aviation authority in your country, and contact them.

For both, I bet finding contact information by google takes less than a minute, so it will be quicker that writing this answer was.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this happened in the US-- harassing wildlife can be a serious offence on various levels (state, federal, etc) even if no specific FAA regulation has been violated.  At least if you can show the pilot knew or should have known that wildlife was being harassed.